# Exception Handling for cv::Rect

Tags: c++, opencv, exception, rect

I have bounding box and I want to crop image with this bounding box.

However I want to increase the size of the bounding box, so I do

```
if ((roi_.x - 5) > 0) // i test here in case the component at the left near border we do not minus otherwise it will be error
{
    roi_.x += (-5);
}
if ((roi_.y - 5) > 0) // i test here in case the component at the left near border we do not minus otherwise it will be error
{
    roi_.y += (-5);
}
if (&(roi_ + cv::Size(10, 0)) != NULL)
{
    roi_.width += 10;
}
if (&(roi_ + cv::Size(0, 10)) != NULL)
{
    roi_.height += 10;
}
```

**For the component at the most right near the border if I increase the width it will be error. The same thing for the height in case the component is at the bottom near the border**

**Are there any ways to handle this exception?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error because `&` requires the **l-value**, which are not for both `roi_ + cv::Size(10, 0)` and `roi_ + cv::Size(0, 10)`.

You need to change

```
if (&(roi_ + cv::Size(10, 0)) != NULL)
...
if (&(roi_ + cv::Size(0, 10)) != NULL)
```

to

```
if ((roi_.x + roi_.width + 10) < img.cols)
...
if ((roi_.y + roi_.height + 10) < img.rows)
```

Comment: roi_x.width you mean roi_.width ?

Comment: @sayvortana Yes, typos. Updated. :)

Comment: Can you explain me the condition 

(roi_.x + roi_.width + 10) < img.cols
(roi_.y + roi_.heigth + 10) < img.rows

I tested on other image n it create problem 
The objective is too prevent the width of rect opencv go out of border of original image

For the component at the most right near the border if I increase the width it will be error. The same thing for the height in case the component is at the bottom near the border

Comment: @sayvortana `roi_.x+roi_.width` is the right x-position of `roi_`, `img.cols` is the width of the image.